# How to get number of users, transactions and volume for a given EOS contract on given day?

Tags: smart-contract

I am trying to figure out how to get the number of users, transactions, and volume for any given EOS contract for any given date.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are websites available that provide this as a service.

If you mean to check yourself with your own metrics, then the only way to do it would be to get a list of all the actions involving the account and then analyse the data from that. This is quite involved though, as you would need to find a reliable node running with full state history, which is proving the be very difficult at the moment.

Several enhancements to the recording of state history are currently being made, in the future this will be a much easier task. When the upgrades are made I will update this answer accordingly.

#### List of websites providing this as a service

[dApp Radar](https://dappradar.com/eos-dapps)

Comment: If people know of other websites that provide this as a service, please edit my answer and append them here

Comment: I am aware of sites like dappradar but I want to be able to run checks on any contract. Creating my own node is not an issue, so any pointers into how to achieve the desired effect on my own node are perfectly acceptable,

Comment: Gotcha, I'll update my answer when I have more time